# Issue with Dynamically Added Questions Not Persisting Display State Across Navigation

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm developing a relatively straightforward application that features a multi-step form, consisting of 8 steps. Users can navigate back and forth through these steps and answer questions at each stage. Specifically, in Step 3, I allow users to create "questions" which are then displayed for interaction in Step 5.

When I create a "question" in Step 3 and proceed to Steps 4 and 5, everything functions as expected: clicking on a question opens it normally. However, if I navigate back to Step 3, add a new question, and then return to Step 5, I can see the new question. But, when I attempt to click on it, its display changes only for the duration of the opening animation before reverting to "display: none".

I'm struggling to clearly articulate this issue, but I have included screenshots and code snippets below, hoping they will provide a clearer understanding of the problem.

File: "affect-question-to-slide.blade.php" (Step 5):

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="affectquestionToSlideForm">
    @if(!empty($questions))
        <div class="space-y-4">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Affectation de mes questions sur les slides</h2>
            <div x-data="{ openQuestion: 1 }" x-init="@this.on('questionAdded', () => { openQuestion = {{ count($questions) }}; })">
                @foreach($questions as $index => $question)
                    @if($question['type'] != "")
                        <div wire:key="question-{{ $index }}" class="p-4 bg-white shadow rounded-lg relative mb-4">
                            <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 bg-indigo-500 text-white py-1 px-3 rounded-br-lg" x-on:click.stop="openQuestion = openQuestion === {{ $index + 1 }} ? null : {{ $index + 1 }}">
                                <p class="cursor-pointer">Question {{ $index + 1 }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div x-show="openQuestion === {{ $index + 1 }}" x-transition>
                                <p class="mt-4"><strong>Question:</strong> {{ $question['question'] ?? 'N/A' }}</p>
                                @if(isset($question['type']))
                                    <p><strong>Type de la question :</strong> {{ $question['type'] }}</p>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Slide :" wire:model="affectquestion.{{ $index }}.slide" class="block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                                        <input type="hidden" wire:model="affectquestion.{{ $index }}.questionID" value="{{ $question['id'] }}">
                                    </div>
                                    @if($question['type'] === 'zone_alphanumerique' || $question['type'] === 'evaluation')
                                        <label for="question{{ $index }}">Définir slide unique pour cette question</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="question{{ $index }}" wire:model="affectquestion.{{ $index }}.slide_unique">
                                    @else
                                        @foreach($question['reponses'] as $indexrep => $reponse)
                                            <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                                <p class="whitespace-nowrap">Saisissez le choix de la réponse : {{ $reponse["texte"] }} ;</p>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Slide :" wire:model="affectquestion.{{ $index }}.choix_de_la_reponse.{{ $indexrep }}.slide" class="flex-1 rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                                            </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <p><strong>Aucune question, revenez en arrière.</strong></p>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <p><strong>Aucune question à afficher.</strong></p>
    @endif

    <div class="flex justify-between mt-4">
        <button type="button" @click="step = Math.max(1, step - 1)" class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Étape précédente</button>
        <button type="submit" @click="step = Math.min(step + 1, 6)" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Étape suivante</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Normal state]
And when I click on it :
[image: Open state]

I've attempted various solutions, including modifying my index or the method of transmitting information. It seems all the necessary information is present in the DOM, suggesting that the problem lies with how the display state is managed.